# PyCharm not recognizing pypiwin32 module, even after verifying installation

Tags: python, pycharm, win32com

I am working on a Outlook email tracker, and to read and write messages, I need the `win32com.client` module.
I've installed it in CMD using `pip3 install pywin32` with a 'successful' installation:

```
Collecting pywin32
  Downloading pywin32-228-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (8.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 8.4 MB 17 kB/s
Installing collected packages: pywin32
Successfully installed pywin32-228

C:\Users\DELL>pip3 install pypiwin32
Collecting pypiwin32
  Downloading pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from pypiwin32) (228)
Installing collected packages: pypiwin32
Successfully installed pypiwin32-223
```

However, when I tried to import win32 in PyCharm using `import win32com.client as client`, PyCharm returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/Projects/MailTrack/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import win32com.client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
```

I have tried to see forum answers, but those deal with `Command Prompt` errors, which doesn't concern.

If you have any helpful information on how to deal with this issue, please help.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: python -m pip install pywin32 try this

Comment: @BijinAbraham
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages
(228)

Comment: In pycharm are you using a venv

Comment: I'm not sure i am

Comment: Can you check if the package exists m the pycharm command line

Comment: I have two versions of python installed :/. I've deleted one, problem solved. Case Closed